# flyway version number change issue

Tags: flyway

We have an application we inherited thats on version 500+, we are not sure why its such a high version, but so be it.  We have been using Flyway for a few years on it now, and have multiple releases.  Sample would be it started as 500.10.4, and we are now on 500.10.20, so 16 releases containing various flyway scripts on a lot of them, but not all.

Anyway, its been determined that for simplification we are to re-version the application to 6.0.0 in the next release.  Is there an easy way to let flyway know of this change, so that if we stand up another instance when it runs through the scripts it would run the 500's first, then go back to the 6's?

Currently our flyway script files are named as such:
V500.10.20_2022.05.12.0000.1__xxxx.sql and so on.  So in theory our next would be
V6.0.0_2022.05.13.0000.1__xxxx.sql

I know that flyway would see version 6 as lower than 500 and ignore it.  We currently have flyway out of order set to false.  Is there any other options to solve this other then to set out-of-order processing to true?

Comment: Could you start from scratch again, or is it important to have the earlier migrations scripts in operation?

Comment: that wouldn't be optimal, because we don't have all instances at the same version currently.  so we would have to try and maintain and get everything up to the latest version pre move to 6, to then "re-baseline" instead of just being able to push out the most recent to bring older systems up to the current.   But it is a possibility if there are no other options

Answer (score 0):

In our situation we do not have any flyway scripts pre version 500.  So what we are going to attempt to do is have a manual script run that will update all the data in our xxx_db_version table to be version 5.00.xxxx instead of 500.xxxx.  This way when we move to 6.0, all of the scripts would be seen as next in the sequence appropriately.  While the versions in this table will then not match previous actual versions of the application this table is not used for the purposes of the actual displayed version of the system or anything, and once we move to version 6, the 500 vs 5 won't really matter.  and the order/sequence will still be maintained.

If this does not work, I will post a follow up.

Comment: You'll have to rename your migration scripts as well, and I suspect you'll need to run flyway repair as I think the filename is part of the checksum.